# Rails 4.1 User Name and Avatar won't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, avatar

Ok... I'm having a very... very weird problem.  When creating a new user, for some odd reason, it won't save the user name or avatar... but only when they register using an email. When they do the exact same thing with Facebook... the user and avatar work fine.  Here's a paste from the log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"QDa9azqwenwcyCWPaYWohDDgSRBST3eCRTcagky984=", "user"=>{"ip_address"=>"77.777.77.777", "name"=>"Jim Beam", "email"=>"jim@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000008d7a048 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140827-9443-132d9ai>, @original_filename="joker bench.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"joker bench.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Redirected to http://example.com/
Completed 302 Found in 599ms (ActiveRecord: 216.3ms)
Started GET "/" for 77.185.98.140 at 2014-08-27 14:51:31 +0000
Processing by DailiesController#index as HTML
  Rendered dailies/index.html.erb within layouts/application (21.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 131ms (Views: 110.7ms | ActiveRecord: 19.6ms)
Started GET "/images/thumb/missing.png" for 77.185.98.140 at 2014-08-27 14:51:31 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/thumb/missing.png"):
```

As you can see the name and image are being received just fine... but then they aren't saved to the database. They just aren't there.  So this sounds like a problem in the model right?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_merit

  acts_as_voter
  acts_as_messageable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :provider, :uid, :name, :remember_me, :avatar, :ip_address, :latitude, :longitude, :avatar, :avatar_file_name, :avatar_content_type, :avatar_file_size, :avatar_updated_at, :country, :current_sign_in_ip, :id
 has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage/
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.ip_address = user.current_sign_in_ip
    user.email = auth.info.email || "#{auth.uid}@facebook.com"
    user.password = user.password_confirmation || SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n=6)
    if auth.provider == "facebook"
      user.name = auth.info.name      
      if auth.info.image.present?
        avatar_url = process_uri(auth.info.image)
        user.update_attribute(:avatar, URI.parse(avatar_url))
      end         
    else      
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    end
    user.save
  end
end
```

As you can see ":name" is an accessible attribute as is ":avatar" and as far as I know they're both setup correctly since it works just fine for Facebook. So why isn't it saving them for the email users? Maybe the controller right?

Here's the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :correct_user?, :except => [:index, :show]
  before_filter :ip_address


  def ip_address
 #   @user.ip_address = request.remote_ip
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.ip_address = request.remote_ip
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    correct_user = @user
  end

end
```

Not getting it... No idea what the problem could be. I'll probably have it figured out by the time someone answers, but I wanted to at least ask. We know the form (I'm using Devise) is working okay because we can see it trying to save the name and avatar in the log.

Anyway let me know if you can come up with anything.

EDIT: Figured out the missing thumbs thing, but it still doesn't work when a user tries to upload a picture or save a user name. It saves the user id, the email address, and the password... so why wouldn't it save the name, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so complicated in the end... I should've known that:

1. If it's working for Facebook login (omniauth) but not working for regular user login (devise)
2. ...then it must be a devise problem.

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

  def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
    registration_params = [:name, :ip_address, :avatar, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]

    if params[:action] == 'update'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {
        |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
      }
    elsif params[:action] == 'create'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {
        |u| u.permit(registration_params)
      }
    end
  end


end
```

So all I need was add :name, :avatar, and :ip_address to the permitted parameters for the devise controller and now everything works fine.